# How to write the SQL query to fetch parent key and it's associated key's

Tags: sql, teradata

Table 1:

```
MBR_KEY   RCD   SID
-------------------
AAA       18    12
BBB       19    12
CCC       18    13
```

Scenarios:

- When `RCD=18` then MBR_KEY AS SKEY
- When `RCD <> 18` then CHECK SID'S ARE SAME AS PARENT MBR_KEY(RCD 18 IS CONSIDERED AS PARENT MBR_KEY)

Output should be like this:

```
    mbrr_key  skey
   ------------------
    aaa       aaa
    bbb       aaa
    ccc       ccc
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking for?  What have you tried?  What results did you get?

Comment: we need to derive the column called skey from the above table considering the conditions such as when RC_ID =18 THEN MBR_KEY Will be the skey. after that we need to check on sid whether same or not for rc_id<>18 and rcid 18. if same,then RC_id 18 member key will be the skey for rc_id 19 too

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
select MBR_KEY, MBR_KEY as SKEY
from yourTable
where RCD=18
union all
select t1.MBR_KEY, t2.MBR_KEY as SKEY
from yourTable t1
,yourTable t2
where t1.SID=t2.SID
and t1.RCD<>18
and t2.RCD=18
order by MBR_KEY

Result:
MBR_KEY SKEY
AAA AAA
BBB AAA
CCC CCC
```

Comment: if you like my answer, please accept and upvote it. thanks.